# looking for current example of MDB consuming messages from remote queue in Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, queue, wildfly, message-queue, message-driven-bean

I have a Wildfly 10 instance which defines a queue, publishes to that queue as well as receives from that queue via an MDB.
That has been have accomplished.

Now I want to add a second Wildfly 10 instance, running on another machine, which will also receive messages from that same (remote) queue defined in the first instance.

I've spent 2 days looking for a current example of how to do this.
There are tons of questions, and some outdated answers.
It seems like the one of the most trivial things to expect from a Q implementation, yet i cannot find any example.

Would someone please refer me to a good and current example (Wildlfy 10) of what needs to be done as far as annotation of the MDB, configuration of the standalone-full.xml, and and security requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into a similar scenario and I had as well trouble to find good documentation.

There are several ways to connect JMS-Queues together:

- JMS core bridges
- JMS bridges
- Connections to a remote server (using a remote connector or properties directly in your MDB).
- JMS-Clustering
- … ?

I created a [demo project](https://github.com/stefangrossmann/remote-jms-example) at Github which uses "JMS-Bridges" to forward messages to another server. The project also uses remote connections to listen to messages of a remote server. The [readme](https://github.com/stefangrossmann/remote-jms-example/blob/master/README.md) explains step by step how I would configure "Wildfly 10" servers that they use the same destination for JMS messages.

The best source of information concerning this topic seems to be the [Messaging documentation of the Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.0](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/) which is as well valid for Wildfly 10.